# WPF Horizontal Scrollbar after resize

Tags: wpf, scrollbar

I have an app build in WPF .
My application is fluid down to 1440 pixels from 1920 pixels.
My issue is that I want the app to display a horizontal scrollbar ONLY when the window size is smaller than 1440 pixels.

Currently if I add a horizontalscrollbarvisibility="Auto" , the app is losing the fluidity. I need it to resize from 1920 to 1440 and only after that have a horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a trigger in your XAML, or you can do it in code:

```
private void MainWindow_OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var actualheigh = this.ActualHeight;
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = actualheigh < 500 ? ScrollBarVisibility.Visible : ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden; //ScrollViewer is the name of you scrollviewer

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @NawedNabiZada .

Small issue was that when the horizontal was appearing we would lose the fluidity. So with a few adjustments to the code of Nawed this worked like a charm:

```
        private void MainWindow_OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        var actualwidth = Application.Current.MainWindow.ActualWidth;
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = actualwidth < 1439 ? ScrollBarVisibility.Visible : ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled; //ScrollViewer is the name of you scrollviewer
        if (ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility == ScrollBarVisibility.Visible)
        {
            this.ActiveItem.Width = 1099;
        }
        else
        {
            this.ActiveItem.Width = Double.NaN;
        }

    }
```